# Avoid Multiple jQueries & Boostrap in an iFrame

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an iFrame where the embedded site uses jQuery plus Bootstrap and my parent site also uses them. Can I remove them in the remote site and rely on my parent website?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

For the scripts part of bootstrap you can avoid it by using the sandbox attribute of the iframe.

```
<iframe id="myIframe" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation">
```

I don't have a solution for the css part yet.

Otherwise load your content with ajax and then display it by moving the content you loaded to the place you want (jquery helps a lot to do so). It shouldn't load any ressource so.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.parent.jQuery) {
    delete window.jQuery;
    delete window.$;
    jQuery = window.parent.jQuery;
    $ = jQuery;
}
```

You can do like this in the iframe.
But be carefull with the selector, the default context will be the parent window's document.